# How to rebase feature branch on dev branch and then update dev

Tags: git, rebase

I have this

```
a -- b -- c -- f                   <-- dev
       \
        d -- e -- g              <-- feature
```

I want this

```
a -- b -- c -- f -- d -- e -- g  <-- dev
```

I know this is related to the rebase command. However, when I type `git rebase dev feature`, commits go to feature branch and dev is not updated. If I use `git rebase feature dev` then last commits are those from master and I have duplicates commits. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: _Do_ you want that? Shouldn't you have c-f-d'-e'-g' on _feature_, so it's trivial to "merge" into dev with a fast-forward?

Comment: I would like to avoid the ugly 'Merge' commit if possible and report all the history made on the feature branch on the dev branch

Comment: That's my point, if you rebase feature on dev (as the title says) you don't need a merge commit, you can fast-forward. But the thing you say you want _isn't_ that.

Comment: My goal is to have all the commits of the feature branch reported in the dev branch. Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Yes, so you want to rebase feature _onto_ dev, then fast-forward "merge" feature _into_ dev. Note you'd typically write that c-f-d'-e'-g' to make it clear those commits are _rewritten_, because they have new parents (d had b, d' has f). A merge doesn't always mean a merge commit, it could be a squash or fast-forward.

Comment: Perfect, it works ! Thank you very much for the explanations, I better understand now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming I want `feature` to remain where it is without moving it (as showing in the final chart), I would do it like this:

```
git checkout dev
git cherry-pick dev..feature
```

That's it

If you want to delete feature branch after that:

```
git branch -D feature
```

In general, a *cleaner* approach (but with more steps) is:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase dev
git checkout dev
git merge feature # (this fill fast-forward to the tip of feature)
git branch -d feature # no need to use -D this time
```

Comment: My bad, I do not need to keep the feature branch. The final goal is to have the "final" dev branch containing all the commits

Comment: This answer is awesome. @bobier2 this is the correct answer, if you don't need feature, then `git branch -D feature` to delete it after cherry-pick.